# Override default username validation of MembershipReboot

Tags: validation, membershipreboot

I'm using Thinktecture IdentityServer with MembershipReboot and i'm trying to find a way to override the default username validation of username.

my case is that I want to allow username to be email or not and not the same as the user email. 
The username validation is configured in `UserAccountService`, I can add validation but I Don't know how to remove them.

I'd simply like to remove the validatior `UsernameDoesNotContainAtSign` and `UsernameOnlyContainsLettersAndDigits`, and do that without any modification of MembershipReboot, through configuration or ?

**Edit:**

Related GitHub issues:

- https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/issues/331
- https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/issues/339
- https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/issues/370

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of these validation rules are hard coded. If you have a use case for changing them, I'd suggest opening an issue on the github issue tracker so we can discuss.